# Как правильно - "с Донбасса" или "из Донбасса"?

Tags: предлоги

Увидел заголовок новости:

> На лечение в Москву доставили 18 тяжелобольных детей из Донбасса

Верно ли употребление предлога со словом "Донбасс"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Давно не бывал я в Донбассе..." - это написано во времена, когда помнили, что сокращение Донбасс - "Донецкий угольный бассейн" (этимологически, "в бассейне"). Предлогам при географических названиях свойственно следовать традиции своего употребления, отсюда споры об устойчивом сочетании "на Украине" (на окраине, на территории) по отношению к возникшему государству. С Донбассом в этом отношении ничего не менялось, поэтому, если не делать акцента на нынешних органах самоуправления этой территории, не видно оснований заменять чем-то предлог "из".

Answer (score 3):

В данном предложении предлог ИЗ, скорее всего,  употреблен верно, так как Донбасс в этой ситуации рассматривается как определенный субъект.

Но использование выражения "с Донбасса" также возможно, если субъект будет рассматриваться как территория, например: беженцы из Донбасса (из конкретного субъекта) и с Донбасса (с территории Донбасса, с прилегающих территорий, то есть без указания четких границ субъекта).

Таким образом, выбор предлогов пока окончательно не устоялся.

Comment: Это правильно. Неправильно то, что политические вещи вроде перехода топонимического понятия в категорию "субъекта" (политического, надо думать) начинает диктовать языковые нормы.  Но в данном случае вынужден согласиться, поскольку оба варианта "из" и "с" Донбасса являются исторической нормой. Как впрочем и предлоги В/НА (как и в слечае с Украиной в целом).

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки это город. Значит, "из Донбасса"

Comment: Это не город. ))) Город -- Донецк.

Comment: Я имела ввиду регион. Всё равно мужского рода, как и город. Из региона - из Донбасса.

Answer (score 0):

В тексте «Большой советской энциклопедии» последовательно употребляется предложно-падежное сочетание с предлогом в – в Донбассе. Вероятно, это связано с внутренней формой наименования, с тем, что Донбасс – это Донецкий бассейн, а сочетание *на бассейне* не нормативно. Предлог в преобладает и в текстах художественной литературы. Однако сочетание на Донбассе также допустимо, так как речь идет о наименовании территории (для сравнения: на Тамбовщине, на Харьковщине). Отмеченной вариативности, вероятно, способствует тот факт, что предлог в употребляется чаще с официальными наименованиями административно-территориальных единиц, а Донбасс — наименование исторически сложившегося региона, который включает в себя части территорий нескольких областей. ***(Информационный портал фонда "Русский мир")***